# How to get the contents of a webpage from shell script

Tags: shell, wget

I have a web mail client and my requirement is to check the count of email in the INBOX and send an email alert if I have more than 10 emails.

We do this manually today by logging into the mail server and check for the mails in the inbox. But in order to automate this, I am planning to prepare a shell script for the same.

I know wget is used to display the contents of a web page. 
So I tried with the below command:
$ wget --http-user=username --http-passwd=password http://server.domain.com/login.asp

It gave the below output:

--11:20:08--  http://server.domain.com/login.asp
           => `login.asp.1'
Resolving server.domain.com... 10.111.186.83
Connecting to server.domain.com[10.111.186.83]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9,749 [text/html]

0% [                                                                                                                             ] 0             --.--K/s             a

It gets connected to the mail server and keeps waiting for a response.

Can somebody help me in displaying the contents of the web page after I logged into the mail server ?

Thanks and Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to display the contents using wget. It depends on how exactly you want your process to go.

```
wget --http-user=username --http-passwd=password http://server.domain.com/login.asp --output-file - --quiet
```

will dump the contents of your file to standard out (the console) and you can pipe or redirect that like the output of any shell command.

```
wget --http-user=username --http-passwd=password http://server.domain.com/login.asp --output-file /path/to/my.file
```

will place the contents of your file into /path/to/my.file and you can act on those like you would a standard file in shell.

Your original command:

```
wget --http-user=username --http-passwd=password http://server.domain.com/login.asp
```

Should still get your page contents and save them a local file ./login.asp

From these spots you should be able to do whatever manner of scraping accomplishes your task.

I used [this page](http://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/) mainly as a reference. Maybe it will help you with your task.

Happy coding! Leave a comment if you have any more questions.